# Windows Developer Preview C# version - features missing?

Tags: c#, windows-8, c#-5.0

I've recently installed Windows 8 Dev preview, though I've ran into quite a few issues. Looking at the new C# API, I can say some features are missing. For example, I cannot find a wait to read a file - classical `StreamReader` no longer takes a filename string but rather an instance of `Stream`.

What am I missing? I've turned the Object Browser inside out, not actually finding anything.

Update: this is obviously the difference between a Portable Class Library and the traditional compilation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx. Hence, is non-portable Windows 8 API available to us yet?

Comment: are you using a WinRT version of .NET?

Comment: @Daniel I suppose so, I've just created a new project from Metro template. I'm not using `WinMD` for sure if that's the question, the output is set to `Windows Metro style Application`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely the WinRT doesn't support that. It should be in the full .NET 4.5.

Comment: I certainly hope so, though I didn't thought Microsoft to expect us to play with a new toy (and actually develop something) without giving us so "marginal" features such as file reading.

Comment: There are other classes in `System.IO`.

Comment: @Mikulas You are supposed to use WinRT classes from `Windows.Storage` namespace to work with files, and specifically to open them as streams. You can then wrap the streams as `System.IO.Stream` using the extension method `AsStream()`.

Answer (score 5):

The developer preview only includes libraries for developing Windows Metro Apps, and not the full framework. This (sadly) also excludes System.Data and a few other well-known namespaces.

Comment: That's because Dev Preview only has VS Express. But you can install the full VS (preview also, of course) from here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543 - which will enable non-Metro project types.

Answer (score 3):

To read/write files from a metro app use the new Window.Storage APIs. I don't believe the classic file read/write will be available in a metro app, due to security and the async nature of metro applications.

Comment: Found that one, though others might still be struggling with this. Thanks! Wishing that other missing functionality would be found as well.

Answer (score 2):

Aside the fact that you using the metro template will unse WinRT (see other answers) you could simply open a stream:

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```